# How intercept these two key: ":" and "."?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom-events, keyboard-input

I need to do something when a user presses <kbd>.</kbd> and something else when an user presses <kbd>:</kbd>.

Is there a way to intercept these two keys with JavaScript, jQuery or other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to intercept these keys on the whole document:

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = (typeof evt.which == "undefined") ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
    if (charCode) {
        var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        if (charStr == ":") {
            alert("Colon!");
        } else if (charStr == ".") {
            alert("Full stop!");
        }
    }
};
```

Marcel Korpel rightly points out in the comments that it's more efficient not to use the `String.fromCharCode()` call; here's a version without:

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = (typeof evt.which == "undefined") ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
    if (charCode) {
        if (charCode == 58) {
            alert("Colon!");
        } else if (charCode == 46) {
            alert("Full stop!");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I agree, only using `String.fromCharCode` seems a bit overkill to me: if I'm not mistaken you can simply test `charCode` being either 46 (`.`) or 58 (`:`).

Comment: Marcel: yes, I agree, and I probably would do that in production code but thought it was clearer what the code is doing with the `String.fromCharCode`. I'll add another version to my answer.